# How to disunite pie chart elements?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've created a Pie Chart Using Illustrator CS6 using Chart tool.

[image]

... and the "Group Selection Tool" to pick single pie chart elements and move them around. All pie chart elements are within one layer and grouped together.

Now I want do the movement automatically. In other words, I want to equally "explode" the Pie Chart elements, like shown on the following figure:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Doing it manually looks quite messy. Optimally, it is possible using effects, because this would enable an adaption of the pie chart's data afterwards... Thank you!

Comment: Could you please, describe how did you create this chart and place a screenshot of the layers? The issue described should be solved in 1 minute....

Comment: @Ilan I expanded my answer

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question. You want to "disunite" the parts and move them to equal distances from the center?

Comment: @Ilan Absolutely, yes!

Comment: Please, look at my answer... I hope someone can correct me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply increase the Stroke width and give it the same (white) background color:

[image]

Comment: This isn't very useful IMHO if you have small slices or large strokes. You can end up with an effect where it seems some slices go closer to the center than others

Answer (score 3):

My answer is "technical", because there are some issues related to the task in question.

If you want to move the segments to equal distance from the center of the pie, it means - to distribute their apexes along the circle, like on the picture -

[image]

As you can see - solving this task leads to another issue - the external arcs looks very strange because there is no correction to new bounds (the same picture without the external circle):

[image]

Thus, we should state that just moving the segments without external arcs corrections can be acceptable only on small distances.

And if try to adjust the segments to the virtual external circle (as I show on the picture), you will loose alignment around the center.

At this point, I should state - your task has no simple solution. 
Probably, the easiest way.... is to distribute the segments to the small distances from the center... manually.

I hope someone could say I am totally wrong...

---

Probably, you will like to cut the uneven apexes and arcs like on this picture -

[image]