# Pull apart pie chart slices in Illustrator but retain stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a pie chart created using Illustrator CC's Pie Graph Tool:

[image]

I want to separate the slices to create a gap in-between.  I see that this has been [asked and answered before](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30234/how-to-disunite-pie-chart-elements), but the answer causes a loss to each slice's stroke (gray becomes white):

[image]

Is there a way to add the dark gray stroke back onto the slices?  I know that technically they are not actually separated, so must they be *ungrouped* or something first?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ungroup the Graph by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. This warning will appear:

[image]

After this you will get lots of groups within groups. To get rid of this press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> some more, until only the slices of your graph are left in the layers panel:

[image]

Now use `Effect > Path > Offset Path` with a negative offset value:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more clarity on when `Offset Path` is used?  I break up the graph into paths, then `Offset Path` with the default options, but it just distorts the shape of each slice.  Also `Minus Front` on the Pathfinder deletes all but one slice

Comment: @EvilDr I updated the post so it now only shows the `Offset Path` solution. If you want to use `Minus Front`you should only select two objects at once: The expanded outline and the one slice you want to subtract it from.

Comment: You, Sir, have just made my day :-)

Comment: Simple *and* elegant.  Answers just do not get better than this one!

Comment: Thank you so much for writing such a detailed, clear solution!

Answer (score 0):

you could just select and choose object>expand

alternatively you could double click the object and add a stroke to the segments

Comment: Okay I figured I need to break up the object before expanding.  However, this does not work because the fill of the shape goes to the edge of the path, so when the path is deleted, the slices still touch one another

Comment: i found this diagram if it helps you <img src=http://www.illustrationetc.com/AIbuds/ExplodedPieChart01.png >. btw if anyone can explain why this img tag isn't working that'd be great. i've tried the markdown script and none of that works.